# Problem understanding a casting issue

Tags: java, casting

Can someone explain to me how the two lines under the comment are compilable?

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C C = new C();

// How can these work?
((G) a).methodG(a);
((B) a).methodG(a);

public class A {
    A methodA() {
        return this;
    }
}
public class B extends A implements G {
    B methodB(A a) {
        return this;
    }
    public G methodG(A a) {
        return (G) this;
    }
}

public class C implements G{
    C methodC(G g) {
        return this;
    }
    public G methodG(A a) {
        return (G) this;
    }
}

public interface G {
    G methodG(A a);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying they do? Because they should throw a class cast exception at run time.

Comment: They throw ClassCastException, as they should. I checked :)

Comment: Actually I don't see how they could work (at runtime).

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot mentioning that why is this compilable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They won't work. You'll get a ClassCastException.

It *will* compile fine, since the compiler doesn't know for a fact that a is not a subclass of A that also implements G (for example B). However, during runtime, when you try to cast, it will fail.

And this is specifically one of the big reasons people shouldn't cast unless there's absolutely no choice. It breaks a lot of the type-safety you get with the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. This is from last years exam in a course I'm taking. The question was indeed to figure out which of many lines where compilable.